# I want to display a summary like this based on the two tables

Tags: php, mysql

My two MYSQL tables are as follows:

Table 1 : citizen

```
=============================
ID |  Name | Sex    | Address |
=============================
5  | James | Male   | India
6  | Shella|Female  | India
7  | Jan   | Male   | NY
8  | May   | Female | USA
==============================
```

Table 2: benefits

```
========================== 
ID| citizen_ID | benefits
==========================
1 | 5          | SSS
2 | 6          | Coco Life
3 | 7          | SSS
4 | 7          | Sunlife
==========================
```

I want to display that looks like this:

```
====================================================================
Address | Total Citizen | Male | Female | SSS | Coco Life | Others |
====================================================================
India   | 2             |  1   |  1     |  1  |    1      |   0    |
NY      | 1             |  1   |  0     |  1  |    0      |   1    |
USA     | 1             |  0   |  1     |  0  |    0      |   0    | 
==================================================================
```

Anybody can give me a hint on how to do this?
My initial code:

```
        $sql = "SELECT  Address,
            count(case when Sex='Male' then 1 end) as male_cnt,
            count(case when Sex='Female' then 1 end) as female_cnt,
            count(*) as total_cnt FROM citizen
            GROUP BY Address";
```

Comment: On one side, I think the desired result can be achieved using a single query, the only question is - how comlex the query will be. On the other side i think query can be simlified greatly, and all the counting logic moved to php. I am not sure which way is more sutable in this situation

Comment: This query `select citizen.Address, citizen.Sex, benefits.benefits from citizen inner join benefits on citizen.ID=benefits.citizen_id` may help you a little bit. It partly produces desidred data, but unfortunatelly it does do any counting. It can be used to do the checks and any counts using php however.

Comment: Yeah, I will try to do some checking @EugeneAnisiutkin.

Comment: =D) I still haven't managed to do it using single SQL query. I keep getting extra people in `Total Citizen`. Right now I am thinking that sinle query solution is too complex. I somewhere heard a saying that any problem in SQL can be solved in a single query, it's just some tomes the query becomes too comlex and changing any data in tables usually leads tro re-writing the whole thing.

Comment: Me too, I tried union, select case and other strategies. For now, I have no luck. :D

Comment: I almost have a workable solution. However i can only post it tommorow or very late today

Comment: Awesome @EugeneAnisiutkin! Thank you. I still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You now simply need to do a `Left Join` from the `Address` table to the `benefits` table. Left join will allows us to consider a `Address` even when there is no corresponding `benefits` entry for any of its citizens.

In order to count total citizens, male count and female count, you now need to use [`COUNT(DISTINCT ID)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) after the join. As Joining may create duplicate rows, as a citizen may have more than one benefits.

Also, in order to count "Other" benefits, we need to ensure that the `benefit IS NOT NULL` and it is `NOT IN ('SSS', 'Coco Life')`.

In multi-table queries, it is advisable to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) for Code clarity (readability) and avoiding ambiguous behaviour.

```
SELECT  
  c.Address,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.Sex = 'Male' THEN c.ID END) AS male_cnt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.Sex = 'Female' THEN c.ID END) AS female_cnt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) AS total_citizen_cnt, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN b.benefits = 'SSS' THEN 1 END) AS SSS_cnt, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN b.benefits = 'Coco Life' THEN 1 END) AS Coco_Life_cnt, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN b.benefits IS NOT NULL AND 
                  b.benefits NOT IN ('SSS', 'Coco Life') THEN 1 END) AS Others_cnt 
FROM citizen AS c 
LEFT JOIN benefits AS b 
  ON b.citizen_ID = c.ID 
GROUP BY c.Address
```

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin as you said in comments above: " I somewhere heard a saying that any problem in SQL can be solved in a single query" :)

Comment: Wow! You really did it @MadhurBhaiya. Now I can sleep well. Thank you.

Comment: @KinandaMata consider marking as accepted answer (green check mark). Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Comment: I have a little twist here. I change the table **benefits** with columns 1) ID 2) benefits_name and added one table **pensioners** which holds the citizen ID, and the pensions ID. Now, I am doing a little changes to display the same output. @MadhurBhaiya, how would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Can this be done? :) Im thingking this must have a join. :D

Comment: Okay @MadhurBhaiya. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

After countless hours of testing, getting help from a cat in code writing, singing shaman songs and ect... I think i made an exapmle that gives desired output. I tested it a bit, and it seems to work.

**However, no matter what i did SQL alone was not enogh to get the job done. And in desperation, I had to resort to using php for realization. And even using php it proved to be a challange.**

Below I am pasting my take on this problem, using mainly php. I only hope that it may help some one or give someone good idea about refactoring the code and making logic easier.

```
<?php

//Connect to DB
$mysql = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test");

if ($mysql->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysql->connect_error);
} 

/*Simplified query - we only get id, address, sex and benefits from our two tabels.
  LEFT JOIN is necessary, because we do not want to miss citizenz that have no benefits.
*/
$sql_statement = "select citizen.ID, citizen.Address, citizen.Sex, benefits.benefits from citizen left join benefits on citizen.ID=benefits.citizen_id";

$results = $mysql->query($sql_statement);
if(!$results)
{
    die("Result is empty! Check the query or data inside tables");
}

/*
* Here we initialize some variables to keep track of further calculations
* 
*   @total_women - array($counry => $amount) - Total number of women, divided by countries, and number of men in each country
*   @total_men - array($counry => $amount) - Total number of men, divided by countries, and number of men in each country
*   @total_benefits - array($counry => array($benefit => $amount)) - Total number of benefits, divided by countries, benefit types and number of benefits in each country
*   @ids - array() - Citizen id's from DB. We have to keep track of them, in order to avoid "extra" people in outr results
*   @Addresses - array() - Addresses from DB. We have to keep track of them to avoid duplicate addresses in our results
*   @$benefit_names() - array() - Keeps the names of benefits, whick we want to count seperatly, All other benefits are "Others"
*/
$total_women = array();
$total_men = array();
$total_benefits = array();
$ids = array();
$Addresses = array();
$benefit_names=array('SSS', 'Coco Life');

//Iterating over recieved results from DB 
foreach($results as $result) {

    //Getting all necessary data
    $id = $result['ID'];
    $address = $result['Address'];
    $sex = $result['Sex'];
    $benefit = $result['benefits'];

    //Ensuring that we don't get duplicate Addresses
    if(!in_array($address, $Addresses)) {
        array_push($Addresses, $address);
    }

    //Ensuring we don't get extra people
    if(!in_array($id, $ids))
    {
        array_push($ids, $id);
        if($sex=='Male') {
            //Dividing men by address
            if(array_key_exists($address, $total_men))
            {
                $total_men[$address]++;
            }
            else
            {
                $total_men[$address] = 1;
            }
        }
        else if($sex=='Female') {
            //Dividing women by address
            if(array_key_exists($address, $total_women))
            {
                $total_women[$address]++;
            }
            else
            {
                $total_women[$address] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    //Ensuring a person has a benefit
    if($benefit) {
        //Dividing benefits by address
        if(array_key_exists($address, $total_benefits)) {
            //Dividing benefits by benefit name.
            if(in_array($benefit, $benefit_names))
            {
                if(array_key_exists($benefit, $total_benefits[$address])) {
                    $total_benefits[$address][$benefit]++;
                }
                else {
                    $total_benefits[$address][$benefit]=1;
                }
            }
            else if(array_key_exists('Others', $total_benefits[$address]))
            {
                $total_benefits[$address]['Others']++;
            }
            else {
                $total_benefits[$address]['Others'] = 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(in_array($benefit, $benefit_names)) {
                $total_benefits[$address][$benefit] = 1;
            }
            else {
                $total_benefits[$address]['Others'] = 1;
            }
        }
    }    
}

//Here after all the manipulations, our hash map looks ugly, to make your life eaier later we fill up the missing parts with 0
foreach($Addresses as $address) {
    foreach($benefit_names as $name) {
        if(!isset($total_benefits[$address][$name])) {
            $total_benefits[$address][$name]=0;
        }
    }
    if(!isset($total_benefits[$address]['Others'])) {
        $total_benefits[$address]['Others']=0;
    }
}


/*
*  At this point all the neseccary calculations are made. We only have to take care of outputting the data.
*/
?>

<html>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Counry</th>
            <th>Total citizen</th>
            <th>Male</th>
            <th>Female</th>
            <?php
            //Here we make sure that all our separate benefit names get theit own column.
            foreach($benefit_names as $benefit) { ?>
                <th><?php echo $benefit; ?></th>
            <?php } 
            //After we displayed all our separate benefits, we display the "Others" column 
            ?>
            <th>Others</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
        $temp;
        //Here we go through all the unique addresses that we met earlier, ad make a roww for each of them
        foreach($Addresses as $address) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $address; //Outputting current address?></td>
                <td>
                <?php
                    //Here we take care of calculating total citizens based on our current address and output them
                    $total_citizen = 0;
                    if(array_key_exists($address, $total_men)) $total_citizen+=$total_men[$address];
                    if(array_key_exists($address, $total_women)) $total_citizen+=$total_women[$address];
                    echo $total_citizen;
                ?>
                </td>
                <!--Here we display number of women, based on our corrent address-->
                <td><?php if(array_key_exists($address, $total_men)) echo $total_men[$address]; else echo "0"; ?></td>
                <!--Here we display number of men, based on our corrent address-->
                <td><?php if(array_key_exists($address, $total_women)) echo $total_women[$address]; else echo "0"; ?></td>
                <?php
                /*
                *  Here is probably the maddest piece of php code.
                *  We have to make sure that the layout of our data values corresponds with our Column headers layout.
                *  For that, we first iterate over our separate benefit names.
                *  By doing this we ensure that all our seperate benefit names are filled with some data
                *  After we filled all seperate benefits are filled, we make sure that "Others" column is also filled with data
                */
                foreach($benefit_names as $benefit) {
                    //Here we have to make sure that there were some benefits. If there were no benefits, then we fill them with 0.
                    if($total_benefits) { ?>
                        <td><? echo $total_benefits[$address][$benefit]; ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                            <td>0</td>
                    <?php }
                }
                //Again, have to make sure that there were some benefits. If there were no benefits, then we fill them with 0.
                if($total_benefits) { ?>
                    <td><?php echo $total_benefits[$address]['Others'] ?></td>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <td>0<td/>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <body>
</html>
```

I placed comments as much as I could, in order to make it easier to understand, what this piece of code does.

Comment: D) I hope this thing works - anyone willing to check? And point out some errors?

Comment: +1 for the efforts. I believe that code lines can be significantly reduced using ternary operators, etc.

Comment: Hello @EugeneAnisiutkin, how are you? Thanks for this great peace of code. I'm sure this will help me a lot. :) Cheers...

Comment: @Kinanda Mata, my piece of code was a desperation). Madhur Bhaiya posted the PURE SQL solution which isf far, far better. Consider marking his answer as accepded to close this question

Comment: Yes, thank you @EugeneAnisiutkin. For now, I am doing a little twist to make this table more dynamic.